# LinkedList char array data in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
class Node
{
private:
    Node* pNext;
    char* name;
public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    Node* getNext();
    char* getname();
    void setNext(Node* pNode);
    void setname(char* pname);
}

void linkedlist:: insert(Node* pNode){
    Node *current;
    pNode->setNext(NULL);

    if(!pHead)
    pHead=pNode;
    else{
        current=pHead;
        while(current->getNext()!=NULL)
        current=current->getNext();
        current->setNext(pNode);
    }
}


void main(){
    linkedlist list;
    Node *temp=NULL;
    char i[200]={0,};
    temp=new Node();
    strcpy(i, "Anna");
    temp->setname(i);
    list.insert(temp);
    temp=new Node();
    strcpy(i, "Jane");
    temp->setname(i);
    list.insert(temp);
    temp=new Node();
    strcpy(i, "Peter");
    temp->setname(i);
    list.insert(temp);
    temp=new Node();
    strcpy(i, "Brooth");
    temp->setname(i);
    list.insert(temp);
    temp=new Node();
    strcpy(i, "Tim");
    temp->setname(i);
    list.insert(temp);
}
```

why the result is not Anna->Jane->Peter->Brooth->Tim
And why the result is Tim->Tim->Tim->Tim->Tim
What should I do?
Whenever char i[200] changed all of the node data changed.
Why? it worked well when i use int data.
It occur only when i use char array.

Comment: No he isn't, he's doing `insert`, so the pointer is there somewhere. Hovewer - the problem is in `setname` probably and you didn't provide the code for it. On a side note: use `string`, not `char*`. This is C++.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Seen that, removed my comment already ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I start writing this a "the" solution has already been accepted by the OP.

However, that solution, using `std::string` to reduce the complexities of handling memory management and indirection through pointers, is in my opinion not an optimal way to learn about handling memory management and indirection through pointers. In other words, to learn about doing *X*, it is in my opinion not a good idea to use a ready-made abstraction that handles the *X*-doing for you. Or even shorter, the relevant "difficult" stuff that `std::string` handles automatically is what the OP apparently is out to learn about.

So.

## Improvement potential for the question.

1. The posted code is **NOT THE REAL CODE**. That's very bad, because it can often waste everybody's time (we're not telepaths). It's guaranteed not the real code because there's at least one missing semicolon, so that it will not compile with any compiler.
2. The posted code is **incomplete**. Most of the class `linked_list` is missing. In particular its constructor is important for assessing the correctness or not of the logic.
3. The posted code is **non-standard**, in this case Microsoft-specific. In standard C and C++ `void main` is invalid, it must be `int main`. For example, the g++ compiler refuses to compile the `void main` in the given code.

Please, for future questions, do post *real code* that is *complete* (but as minimal as you can make it), and *standard* C++ (to the degree that that's practical).

## Why the names appear to be the same, & how to fix it.

All nodes point to the same name buffer.

To fix that *without using `std::string`*, you need to make sure that each node points to a unique name buffer.

And one way to do that is to allocate each node's buffer dynamically, using `new[]`.

## How to create a duplicate of a string.

The **DRY** principle: *Don't Repeat Yourself*.

According to this principle it's a bad idea to use `new[]` directly each place you want to add a string to a list, and also it's a bad idea to copy the string to the new buffer each such place. The reason is that all this duplication of code easily can introduce small bugs, which adds to the time used to find and fix bugs. Worse, if code duplication is done by the convenient method of copy-and-modify, then *bugs can be duplicated*, and due to Murphy's law that will happen – often.

Instead the call to `new[]` and the copying of the string should be *centralized*, e.g. in a function called `duplicate`, since that (duplicate string, not duplicate bug) is both what it does and what it produces:

```
#include <string.h>     // strcpy, strlen
#include <stddef.h>     // ptrdiff_t

typedef ptrdiff_t Size;

auto duplicate( char const* const s )
    -> char*
{
    Size const buffer_size = 1 + strlen( s );
    return strcpy( new char[buffer_size], s );
}
```

The `ptrdiff_t` type is the type of a pointer difference expression. It's therefore large enough to handle any real size, and on 32-bit and 64-bit systems it's the signed equivalent of unsigned `size_t`. It's used above instead of `size_t`  as a generally good practice, to avoid unsigned integer types *for numbers*, because implicit conversion up to unsigned type can give very unexpected results, resulting in bugs.

The `duplicate` function is essentially a Do It Yourself C++ variant of the old *nix C `strdup`. I included an implementation so that you can see how it works. To be a really complete DIY implementation – you may try this out for yourself – also `strlen` and `strcpy` should be implemented, with perhaps more modern unshortened names.

Why doesn't the C standard library include `strdup`? I don't know, it's a big mystery. But for C++ programming *it's good that it's missing*, because the C function would have used `malloc` and `free`, while in C++ the very strong convention is to use `new[]` and `delete[]`, so that one could inadvertently use the wrong deallocation function…

## Managing a dynamic object's lifetime by unique ownership.

For each executed `new[]` there should be exactly one executed `delete[]`. This can be difficult to achieve. When there is no corresponding `delete[]` the program **leaks memory**, and when there are two or more `delete[]`s for the same object the program has **Undefined Behavior**.

A general C++ solution is to use a special class whose constructor either accepts a newly `new[]`ed pointer, or performs a `new[]` itself, and whose destructor performs `delete[]`.

This object – which can be a `Node` – is then said to **own** the dynamically allocated object whose lifetime it manages.

The standard library provides several general and reusable owner object classes called **smart pointers**, including `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, but the point here is to do it all oneself, so…

For example, each node's constructor can just call `duplicate` in order to give the node its own separate duplicate of the specified string. The `new[]` in the constructor (performed via the call to `duplicate`) then needs to be matched by a corresponding `delete[]` in the destructor, so as not to leak memory. A first attempt at defining a `Node` class can then look like this:

```
// 1st attempt:
struct Node
{
    Node*           p_next;
    char const*     name;

    ~Node()
    { delete[] name; }

    Node( char const s[] )
        : p_next( nullptr )
        , name( duplicate( s ) )
    {}
};
```

But this has a potential problem, namely, what happens if a node's `name` is reassigned?

Then, unless the code doing the assignment first performs a `delete[]`, or copies the existing pointer, the pointer to the buffer will be lost, and it will be impossible to deallocate that buffer (no info about where it is), and memory will be leaked.

This problem can be solved by either making `name` constant (adding `const`), or making it `private`, with a **getter** function, also known as an **accessor**.

But there is also the opposite problem, namely, what happens if a node is copied?

Then (with the definition above) you will have two or more node objects with the same name buffer pointer, each taking responsibility for calling `delete[]`, resulting in two or more `delete[]` calls for the same object, with Undefined Behavior as result.

The simplest way to *take charge of copying* is to disallow it. Copying can be disallowed by declaring `private` copy constructor and copy assignment operators. Or one can inherit from a class that does that, at the risk of a certain compiler producing silly-warnings about its inability to generate a copy assignment operator for the class. Also note that declaring a `const` member only prohibits copy assignment, not copy construction. So to take charge it's necessary to declare at least one copy constructor, which is known as **The rule of 3**: if you need either a destructor, a copy constructor or an assignment operator, then (e.g. to take charge of copying) you probably need all three.

```
// 2nd. attempt, conforming to the rule of 3:
class Node
{
private:
    char const*     name_;

    Node( Node const& );                    // Copy constructor, no such.
    Node& operator=( Node const& );         // Copy assignment, no such.

public:
    Node*           p_next_;

    auto name() const
        -> char const*
    { return name_; }

    ~Node()                                 // Destructor.
    { delete[] name_; }

    Node( char const s[] )
        : name_( duplicate( s ) )
        , p_next_( nullptr )
    {}
};
```

Now there's no *technical* problem, but there's a design level and usage problem, namely that one logical attribute, the name, is accessed via a member function, while another logical attribute, the next pointer, is accessed directly as a data member. A programmer using an editor without auto-completion might get a bit annoyed by forgetting to type function call parentheses for the name access, or typing a parenthesis where it shouldn't be for the next pointer access.

One solution is to make *both* members `private`, and provide both a **setter** function and a getter function for the next pointer. But while that provides a uniform notation, it's generally a lot of verbosity. The protection of the name member, at some verbosity cost, serves to prevent incorrect use, possibly incorrect use with UB, which is important. A similar protection of the next pointer would just be for uniform notation. And a `Node` is such a low level thing that it doesn't really make sense.

A better idea is therefore to encapsulate the lifetime management of a dynamically allocated string, in a dedicated **owner class** (class of owner objects), e.g. like …

```
class String_value
{
private:
    char const*     chars_;

    String_value( String_value const& );            // Copy constr., no such.
    String_value& operator=( String_value const& ); // Copy assign, no such.

public:
    auto pointer() const
        -> char const*
    { return chars_; }

    ~String_value()
    { delete[] chars_; }

    String_value( char const* const s )
        : chars_( ::duplicate( s ) )
    {}
};

// 3rd attempt: using a dedicated owner class.
struct Node
{
    String_value    name;
    Node*           p_next;

    Node( char const s[] )
        : name_( s )
        , p_next_( nullptr )
    {}
};
```

This definition provides both some measure of safety for the lifetime management, and *convenience*, e.g. writing just `new Node( "Anna" )`. :-)

## A linked list as a collection class.

While each node manages the lifetime of a dynamically allocated string, who or what manages the lifetime of a node?

A natural owner is a dedicated list object. One can easily do linked list management by directly handling the nodes, but a dedicated list object can add some measure of safety by *centralizing* the lifetime management, and other aspects. In the question's posted code there is a linked list class, but neither the class definition nor its constructor is shown, so it's unclear what its responsibilities are.

One difference compared to the nodes is that the list object will own (manage the lifetime of) a whole collection of objects. This is generally known as a **collection class**. For example, the standard library's "container" classes are collection classes.

There are a whole slew of design options to choose from. In particular whether the list class should expose nodes as such (good for learning and the least amount of scaffolding code) or whether it should be an opaque container of values, where it's just an implementation aspect that those values – here strings – are stored in list nodes. The standard library's `std::list` acts as an opaque container, while the class below shamelessly exposes nodes as such:

```
class Linked_list
{
private:
    Node    head_;
    Node*   p_last_;

    Linked_list( Linked_list const& );              // Copy constr., no such.
    Linked_list& operator=( Linked_list const& );   // Copy assign., no such.

public:
    auto first_node() const
        -> Node const*
    { return head_.p_next; }

    void append( Node* const p_node )
    {
        p_last_->p_next = p_node;
        p_last_ = p_node;
    }

    ~Linked_list()
    {
        while( Node* const p_doomed = head_.p_next )
        {
            head_.p_next = p_doomed->p_next;
            delete p_doomed;
        }
    }

    Linked_list()
        : head_( "" )
        , p_last_( &head_ )
    {}
};
```

A **header ndoe** is here directly part of the list object. It's not part of the logical sequence of *values*, but is part of the linked sequence of *nodes*. As part of the linked list it simplifies insertion and deletion, e.g. here that it's possible to maintain a pointer to the last *node*, even when the sequence of *values* is empty.

A subtle optimization observation: the header node will generally not need to have a value, so by arranging things "just so" it's possible to use just the link part of a node as header node. This is more or less equivalent to the scheme of having a pointer to first node instead of having a header node, and having a pointer to the pointer to the last node, instead of having a pointer to the last node. Okay, eyes maybe glazing over, so, now how to use it all.

## How to use it all.

The main program re-coded to use the above functionality:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Linked_list list;
    list.append( new Node( "Anna" ) );
    list.append( new Node( "Jane") );
    list.append( new Node( "Peter") );
    list.append( new Node( "Brooth") );
    list.append( new Node( "Tim") );

    for( Node const* p = list.first_node();  p != nullptr;  p = p->p_next )
    {
        cout << p->name.pointer() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason they all say "Tim" is because you're setting `name` in `Node` to point to the `char i[200]` buffer in `main` each time you call `setname`.

Because of this everytime you `strcpy` you are replacing the string in all the nodes. Because "Tim" is the last name you set this is what they'll all point to!

A better, and more C++, solution would be to store `name` as a `std::string` instead:

```
class Node
{
private:
  Node* pNext;
  std::string name;
public:
  Node();
  ~Node();
  Node* getNext();
  const std::string &getname() const
  {
    return name
  }

  void setNext(Node* pNode);
  void setname(consts std::string &pname)
  {
    name = pname;
  }
}
```

Comment: "A better, and more C++, solution would be to store name as a std::string " ... and not to use linked lists at all.

Comment: SInce the OP is clearly doing an exercise to learn about dynamic allocation and deallocation, and handling pointers, it's **not** a good idea to suggest `std::string` here. For general learning and even for professional code (in general) it's good advice. For learning about how to do its job, however, it's ungood to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that member function setname the realization of which you did not show simply assigns pname to data member name. As pname is always the same that is it equal to the address of the furst element of array i then all data members name of each node contain the same address and the last value that is stored at this address is string literal "Tim".

Answer (score 0):

Currently, all of your nodes are accessing the same memory (i) for their name. They all change i, and they all display i. So whatever is stored in i will be used for all of your nodes. To create unique values for each of your nodes, you need to have a distinct set of memory allocated to each node's name parameter. If you use std::string, the string class will handle this memory allocation for you. If you just use your own char* members it is up to you to decide where and how you handle this memory allocation, either dynamically by newing up memory (and hopefully deleting it later), or by statically allocating a separate array for each node you create. Considering that the nodes are dynamically allocated themselves, and you probably want your list to be able to grow at run time, you most likely want to dynamically allocate your memory for each name. You should seriously consider letting std::string handle that for you though, or using a smart pointer from the std if you must.